Bianchi's identity and introducing magnetic charges in Maxwell's theory
In the covariant formulation of electromagnetism, we have Maxwell's equations
$$
\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu} = J^\nu \quad \text{and}\quad \partial_\mu \phantom{}^*F^{\mu\nu} = 0.\tag{1}
$$
Now, it is usually said that if magnetic charges existed, these equations would be modified to
$$
\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu} = J^\nu_e \quad \text{and}\quad \partial_\mu \phantom{}^*F^{\mu\nu} = J^\nu_{m},\tag{2}
$$
where $J^\nu_e$ and $J^\nu_m$ are the electric and magnetic currents, respectively.
The problem that is overlooked is that –at least in $U(1)$/Maxwell's theory– Bianchi's identity, which is derived from very simple considerations, enforces the usual $J_m=0$.
Of course, I guess that I am far from being the only person who has realised this, but nevertheless (2) is usually thrown around in lectures and books. So my question is, what is the workaround to make (2) work? Do we throw out $U(1)$ and move to larger, non-abelian gauge groups? Or do we take a drastically different approach

Magnetic 4-currents are compatible with gauge invariance with a caveat. The idea is to view the loops of magnetic currents as defect lines of the gauge field. This is similar to dislocation lines for solids. The difference is that for a crystal in $D$ dimensions, the gauge group is $U(1)^D$. In QFT, these magnetic current loops are ‘t Hooft lines and play the role of nonlocal disorder parameters
Mathematically, let $A$ be the potential vector so that $F=dA$. When you have a magnetic current loop, $A$ will not be defined on the loop. This is not surprising as this is the case even for electric current loops. The novelty is that it cannot be globally defined either. At best you need to exclude a surface whose boundary is the current loop. The compacity of the $U(1)$ gauge group imposes compatibility restrictions two gauge fields describing the same EM field. This leads to the quantization of magnetic charge.
When looking at a temporal slice, the loop becomes a pair of opposite magnetic charges. The surface where $A$ is not defined is now a curve joining them, the Dirac string.

(+1) Is a Halbach array effectively a magnetic monopole when viewed from far enough distance?

Thanks. You cannot emulate magnetic monopoles in classical magnetism, the flux is always zero. Actually, for the Halbach array it is rather the opposite. You are creating loops of flux, so from afar, it just looks like a dipole field.

@James After a bit more thought, yes, for a Halbach array, it looks like you have flux lines exiting the surface like it has a distribution of magnetic charges. However, a careful analysis shows that within the surface, you have very localised magnetic fields which close the loops, so no actual magnetic charges.

@LPZ I fear that your reply is too advanced for me... (but thank you!) What are defect lines?

Tried my best :). I was referring to linear crystallographic defect especially dislocations. For a mathematical treatment, you can check out Landau & Lifschitz book on elastic media. The analogy is not mathematically exact, so don't read too much into it. You can apply gauge theories to crystals though. Checkout for example Hagen Kleinert's book on the matter
